# jQuery Mobile Background

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a page built in jQuery Mobile, and I am trying to use css to insert a background, but there's this grey background there already.

How do I get rid of it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<title>GeoBird</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>SketchUp</h1>
  </div>

<style>
#buttons {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 175px;}

body {
    background: url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
</style>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quitbutton").click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    });
});
  </script>






<div id="buttons"> 
 <a  href="game.html" data-role="button" data-iconpos="bottom">Start</a>
 <a  href="" data-role="button" data-iconpos="bottom">Options</a>
  <a  href="" data-role="button" data-iconpos="bottom">Credits</a>
   <a  id="quitbutton" data-role="button" data-iconpos="bottom">Quit</a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Which grey background you are talking about.

Comment: Please fix your jsfiddle. You cannot use relative paths in jsfiddle because it will link to files on jsfiddle.net itself. Please re-post with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSfiddle it is not taking background image because of path issue. Please check Image path is correct in css or not.

I have tried to add background image from google image and it works properly.

```
<style>  
body {
      background: url('http://colorvisiontesting.com/plate%20with%205.jpg');
     background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    }
</style>
```

It works properly. So please check once your image path is correct or not.

thanks

Comment: i am testing your answer, 1 second

Comment: what result you get..I hope it will be worked. And please In image url there is unnecessary space so remove that in my answer..

Comment: Hi Please check on  http://jsfiddle.net/uyH5G/ url it is working in my answer image url is incomplete. Please check it is working for me..It is taking background image.

Comment: i found what was going wrong, my div ids were not formatted correctly